# parameters in query sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, parameters

I have the following pandas dataframe

Column1

```
Column1         Column2
10572           ORCHESTRA
18125           ORCHESTRA
21906           ORCHESTRA
22106           ORCHESTRA
```

I want to put value in the query like this

```
    AND
(colunm2 , column1) IN (
    ('ORCHESTRA',  18423),
    ('ORCHESTRA',  14931),
    ('ORCHESTRA',  12573),
    ('ORCHESTRA',   8849),
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_column'] = df['Column2'].astype(str) + df['Column1'].astype(str)

df = df[df['new_column'].isin(['ORCHESTRA18423', etc.])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't able to understand your question but may be it will help for you,

**If you want to fetch column1 value from table**

AND column1 in (select Column1 from yourtable)
AND column2 in ('ORCHESTRA')

or

AND column1 in (select Column1 from yourtable)
AND column2 in (select Column2 from yourtable)

**If you want to pass values**

AND column1 in (18423,14931,12573,8849)
AND column2 in ('ORCHESTRA')